# Change in label location doesn't take effect before thread sleep

Tags: java, swing, io, thread-safety, listener

I'm trying to make a little program which will display a small square in a random place on the screen. Then once I click on the square I want the square to disappear and after a small random time I want another square to appear in another random place on the screen.

Here's my code:

```
package mouse;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Created by owner on 07/11/2014.
 */
public class MouseTrainer extends JFrame implements MouseListener {
    File record = new File("src\\main\\resources\\mouseRecord.txt");
    Random rand = new Random();
    JLabel lbl;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    Thread recorder;


public MouseTrainer() throws IOException {
    super("GFXAccelerator");
    recorder = new Thread(new MouseRecorder(record));

    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("src\\main\\resources\\square.png"));
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);


    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setOpaque(true);
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    lbl = new JLabel();
    lbl.setSize(20, 20);
    lbl.setIcon(icon);
    lbl.setLocation(0, 0);
    contentPane.addMouseListener(this);


    contentPane.add(lbl);


    this.setContentPane(contentPane);
    this.setSize(2560, 1390);

    this.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    MouseTrainer mr = new MouseTrainer();


}

public void randomPosition() throws IOException {
    x = rand.nextInt(2540);
    y = rand.nextInt(1350);

    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(record, "NEW DESTINATION!\n", true);
    lbl.setLocation(x, y);
}


private void hideSquare(){
    lbl.setBounds(new Rectangle(new Point(3000, 3000), lbl.getPreferredSize()));
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    if((e.getX() > x && e.getX() < x+20) && e.getY()>y && e.getY() <y+20){
        System.out.println("hello");
        hideSquare();
        try {

            FileUtils.writeStringToFile(record, "Destination clicked: x=" + x + "; y=" + y + "\n", true);
            Thread.sleep(500 +rand.nextInt(5000));
            randomPosition();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {


}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

}


}
```

I listen for the mouse click, and on the mouse click I change the location of the square to an area of screen and do a Thread.sleep() to wait and draw the next square. Unfortunately the location doesn't get changed to an off screen location and the square stays in the same place.

Can someone explain why this is happening and perhaps how I can make the square disappear after the user clicks on it and before the next square appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google `Thread.sleep` and Swing GUI on this site, and you'll see that the same thing is happening here in your program that is happening in all the other similar programs and similar questions.

- Don't call `Thread.sleep(...)` on the Swing EDT as that just puts your whole GUI to sleep.
- Do use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead.
- Do Google and search this site for similar questions.
- Please check out [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)
- Also check out the [Swing Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html)